# «Тупой, как глиняный» — это какой?

Tags: лексика, значение-слов, как, сравнительный-оборот

> И слышал, как Аннушка шарила сонными руками, искала задвижку. И сразу в сенях обхватила теплая тишина. Угарцем пахло, капустой и мокрыми валенками. Филипп протопал к себе и долго не мог выковырять мерзлым пальцем спичку. Чистенько было в комнате, и на шашечной скатерти стоял ужин, прикрытый тарелкой. Лампа трещала, ворчливо разгоралась. *И уж стал виден **комод, тупой, как глиняный**, и на нем вазы с пупырышками и пыльные бумажные розы.* И вспомнился рояль — горит лаком, а стол держит альбом.
> [Б. С. Житков. Виктор Вавич](https://books.google.ee/books?id=djnaCQAAQBAJ&pg=PT236&lpg=PT236&dq=%D0%98%20%D1%83%D0%B6%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4,%20%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9,%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9,%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8B.&source=bl&ots=M6fGDXnc_X&sig=ACfU3U2iJuIO3exWG78Z6bIA9CJLHtXrYw&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjp_6_WrJ75AhWss4sKHft_ACQQ6AF6BAgDEAM#v=onepage&q=%D0%98%20%D1%83%D0%B6%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%2C%20%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%20%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%20%D1%81%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BF%D1%8B%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B7%D1%8B.&f=false)

Пришли на память сравнения со словом "тупой": как валенок, как пробка, как дрова. А вот с таким выражением я встретилась впервые.
Попадалось ли оно вам и какое значение имеет?

Answer (score 2):

Как валенок, так и иной предмет с заваленными углами — скруглёнными формами или смягчёнными гранями, можно характеризовать этим неоднозначным словом: тупой инструмент, тупой угол, тупой носик, тупая игла, тупой зад машины.

Comment: Всё, что сделано из глины, — с заваленными углами?

Comment: Из глины, даже не имея навыка, проще всего получить мягкие формы. Утверждаю, что слово *тупой* в приведённом тексте надо принимать в его прямом значении.

Comment: Спасибо, *shampar*.  Скругленный (округленный, закругленный) — это понятно. А вот для причастий "заваленный" и "смягченный" я подходящего значения не нашла (http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BC%D1%8F%D0%B3%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C), хотя — вроде все понятно.

Comment: Добиваясь плавности (смягчённости) форм предмета, выпуклости на его поверхности срезают, а вогнутости заполняют — заваливают или заливают.